Active Directory users in Windows Docker container
Is there any workaround to use Active Directory user accounts within the Windows Docker container?
I looked around and seems like there is one work around using GMSA Integrating Windows Authentication in Docker Container ASP.NET App
Is that the only option available? Or is there any other workaround?
(My organization doesn't allow GMSA creation)
